# How do I identify whether I am installing or uninstalling the WiX msi package?

Tags: c#, .net, wix, windows-installer, custom-action

I have been trying to install my service via a custom action. The installation part does well, and as soon as I install the msi package it installs the service as well, but uninstalling is not working for me and does not uninstall the service.

Comment: You should post your WiX source. ServiceInstall is used to install services, ServiceControl (Remove) is used to delete them, and we can't say what's wrong without looking at your code. C# has nothing to do with this. If you are using installer classes or code, it's not needed.

Comment: <Binary Id="CustomActionBinary" SourceFile="Libraries\CustomAction.CA.dll"/>
    <CustomAction Id="CustomActionID"  Impersonate="no" BinaryKey="CustomActionBinary" DllEntry="CustomActionStart" Execute="deferred" Return="ignore"/>    
    
    <InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom Action='CustomActionID' After='InstallFiles'></Custom>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>

Comment: above is my code, the behavior of this code is that when I install the msi it calls the custom action but not when I uninstall it and just removes the files . My custom action is responsible for installing and uninstalling the service.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution of my problem.
First of all I removed all the Custom actions as they were becoming difficult to handle, then as suggested by **[PhilDW](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3261150/phildw)** I used **ServiceInstall** and **ServiceControl**.

Now my .msi was installing the service but uninstalling was still a problem, then I created new GUIDs for my service component and the Product and that solved the problem. Now my .msi file is installing/uninstalling my service perfectly.

Cheers!!!